# List doesnt hold values inside and clear

Tags: python, list

I am creating to school SAS (internet online marks from school ) and I have one problem. I created function to generate some marks but when I delete the funcion the marks will just disapear.
I have two files,this is the one when we are executing our functions

```
import sas as s
s.generateGrades()
s.completeAverage()
```

and in this, there are all of functions

```
import random
def generateGrades() :
    for i in range(30) :
        continuousClassification.append([
            subjects[random.randint(0,len(subjects)-1)],
            "2016"+"-"+str(random.randint(1,12))+"-"+str(random.randint(1,30)),
            str(random.randint(1,5)),
        ])
def addGrade() :
    subject = input("Zadejte předmět zkratkou: ")
    date = input("Zadejte datum ve formátu RRRR-MM-DD : ")
    grade = input("Zadejte známku, pokud žák nepsal zadejte N :")
    continuousClassification.append([subject,date,grade])
def searchBy(typeOf,source) :
    if typeOf == "predmetu" :
        for i in range(len(continuousClassification)) :
            if(continuousClassification[i][0] == source) :
                print("Známka ",continuousClassification[i][2])
    else :
        for i in range(len(continuousClassification)):
            if (continuousClassification[i][1] == source):
                print(i, ".", "známka ", continuousClassification[i][2])
def averageOfSubject(subject) :
    all = 0
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(continuousClassification)) :
        if continuousClassification[i][0] == subject :
            all+=int(continuousClassification[i][2])
            total+=1
    if all == 0 :
        return "V předmětu "+subject+" nemáte žádnou známku"
    return round(all/total,2)
def completeAverage() :
    for subject in subjects :
        print("Průměr z ",subject," je ",averageOfSubject(subject))
subjects = ["MAT","CJL","DEJ","FYZ","TEV","ANJ","NEJ","PAD","GRW","TVY","ASW","TEA","ZAE"]
continuousClassification = []
```

I want to generate marks and I want to remember it all time, but it doesnt do it. When I run  my script without generating new ones it just dont load them and I have to load new again

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "when I delete the function the marks will just disappear"?

Comment: in a first file I am calling all functions so I call to generate the list and then other function, then I remove (dont call) the function and I call some other function and this will not get done, because the list is empty

Comment: You don't seem to write/serialize the data to disk anywhere.  There are many ways, but a simple start would be to look up the json module for serializing object.  You can use dump()/load() to save the data to disk and read it again on the execution of the script.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: Do you restart the skript? Then why do you think the list persists between different runs?

Comment: i can add an videa if you want

Comment: oh I reallize my mistake I am sorry :D Thanks all for help

Comment: I think using the `sqlite3` package would help you "remember the courses and grades all the time"

Comment: @FilipBartoš if you've realized your mistake, you can just delete your question, as it's unlikely to be answered in its current form.